# How to categorize a ManyToMany by field type in Django REST Framework serializer?

Tags: json, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Not sure if the title question is worded correctly.

But basically the JSON output is setup how I want it to look. I just need to differentiate between
each effect type in the output.

It currently displays all effects for each effect type as I just repeated the process I did for flavors while I figure out a solution.

Any guidance in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

## models.py

```
class Effects(models.Model):
    POSITIVE = 'positive'
    NEGATIVE = 'negative'
    MEDICAL = 'medical'
    EFFECTTYPES = [ 
        (POSITIVE, _('Positive')), 
        (NEGATIVE, _('Negative')), 
        (MEDICAL, _('Medical')),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    etype = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=EFFECTTYPES, default=POSITIVE, verbose_name="Effect Type")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]
        verbose_name = _('Effect')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Effects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Flavors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]
        verbose_name = _('Flavor')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Flavors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Strain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    INDICA = 'indica'
    SATIVA = 'sativa'
    HYBRID = 'hybrid'
    RACE = [ 
        (INDICA, _('Indica')), 
        (SATIVA, _('Sativa')), 
        (HYBRID, _('Hybrid')),
    ]
    race = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=RACE, default=INDICA, verbose_name="Race")
    effects = models.ManyToManyField(Effects, blank=False, verbose_name="Effect")
    flavors = models.ManyToManyField(Flavors, blank=False, verbose_name="Flavor")
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]
        verbose_name = _('Strain')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Strains')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
class StrainViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Strain.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = StrainSerializer
```

## serializer.py

```
class EffectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Effects
        fields = ('name', 'etype')

class FlavorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Flavors
        fields = ('name', )

class StrainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    effects = EffectsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    flavors = FlavorsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Strain
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'race', 'effects', 'flavors', 'desc')

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        def get_flavors_list(self, instance):   
            return list(instance.flavors.values_list('name', flat=True))

        def get_effects_list(self, instance):
            return list(instance.effects.values_list('name', flat=True))

        return {
            instance.name: {
                "id": instance.id,
                "race": instance.race,
                "flavors": get_flavors_list(self, instance),
                "effects": {
                    "positive": get_effects_list(self, instance),
                    "negative": get_effects_list(self, instance),
                    "medical": get_effects_list(self, instance)
                }
            }
        }
```

## current json output

```
{
        "Afpak": {
            "id": 1,
            "race": "hybrid",
            "flavors": [
                "Chemical",
                "Earthy",
                "Pine"
            ],
            "effects": {
                "positive": [
                    "Depression",
                    "Dizzy",
                    "Happy",
                    "Hungry",
                    "Insomnia",
                    "Lack of Apeitite",
                    "Pain",
                    "Relaxed",
                    "Sleepy",
                    "Stress"
                ],
                "negative": [
                    "Depression",
                    "Dizzy",
                    "Happy",
                    "Hungry",
                    "Insomnia",
                    "Lack of Apeitite",
                    "Pain",
                    "Relaxed",
                    "Sleepy",
                    "Stress"
                ],
                "medical": [
                    "Depression",
                    "Dizzy",
                    "Happy",
                    "Hungry",
                    "Insomnia",
                    "Lack of Apeitite",
                    "Pain",
                    "Relaxed",
                    "Sleepy",
                    "Stress"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

## desired json output

```
{
        "Afpak": {
            "id": 1,
            "race": "hybrid",
            "flavors": [
                "Chemical",
                "Earthy",
                "Pine"
            ],
            "effects": {
                "positive": [
                    "Happy",
                    "Hungry",
                    "Relaxed",
                    "Sleepy",
                ],
                "negative": [
                    "Dizzy",
                ],
                "medical": [
                    "Depression",
                    "Insomnia",
                    "Lack of Apeitite",
                    "Pain",
                    "Stress"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to come back here earlier, I solved it already if anyone needed.

I'm pretty sure there's a nicer way to write this, but for now this will do.

## serializer.py

```
class StrainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    effects = EffectsSerializer(many=True)
    flavors = FlavorsSerializer(many=True)
    positive_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    negative_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    medical_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Strain
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'race', 'effects', 'flavors', 'desc', 'positive_types', 'negative_types', 'medical_types')

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        def get_flavors_list(self, instance):   
            return list(instance.flavors.values_list('name', flat=True))

        def get_positive_types(self, instance):
            return list(instance.effects.filter(etype='positive').values_list('name', flat=True))

        def get_negative_types(self, instance):
            return list(instance.effects.filter(etype='negative').values_list('name', flat=True))

        def get_medical_types(self, instance):
            return list(instance.effects.filter(etype='medical').values_list('name', flat=True))

        return {
            instance.name: {
                "id": instance.id,
                "race": instance.race,
                "flavors": get_flavors_list(self, instance),
                "effects": {
                    "positive": get_positive_types(self, instance),
                    "negative": get_negative_types(self, instance),
                    "medical": get_medical_types(self, instance)
                },
                "desc": instance.desc
            }
        }
```